# PrimeNG 8 treetable is not expanding after filter

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have been trying to expand the tree row after global filtered. Unfortunately, it is not working and not throwing error also.

It is working great without a global filter.

**I have implemented as per PrimeNg documentation**

Applied frameworks

```
Angular8
PrimeNg8
```

Can any expert provide your valuable feedback?

**HTML**

```
<input class="text-center" type="text" pInputText  placeholder="-- Input Value --" (input)="tt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" />
<p-treeTable #tt [value]="entityListTree" [columns]="entityListTreeColumns"     
(onNodeExpand)="onNodeExpand($event)"  (onNodeCollapse)="onNodeCollapse($event)"  [showLoader]="showLoader" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" [first]="first" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 20, 50, 100]"
(onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" (onRowUnselect)="onRowUnselect($event)" (sortFunction)="treeTableDateSort($event)" [customSort]="true" [globalFilterFields]="entityListTreeColumns" >
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [ttSortableColumn]="col.field">             
    <!-- Heading comes here -->
    </th>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData" let-columns="columns">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!-- Data comes here -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
</p-treeTable>
```

**TS**

```
createLazyNodes() {
  this.entitySetUpService.findAllEntitySetUpList().subscribe(
    (res) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.entityListTree = []
        res.forEach((row) => {
          let node = {
            data: {
              entityName: row['entityName'],
              status: row['status'],
              entityCode: row['entityCode'],
              createdDateString: row['createdDateString'],
            },
            leaf: !row.hasAssigned,
            children: []
          };
          this.entityListTree.push(node)
        })
      }, 2000)
    },
    (error) => {
      this.notificationService.showError(error.message)
    }
  )
}
onNodeExpand(event) {
  this.showLoader = true;
  const node = event.node;
  const entityCode = node.data.entityCode
  node.children = []
  this.entitySetUpService.allAssignedEntity(entityCode).subscribe(
    (res) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showLoader = false;
        res.forEach((row) => {
          let children = {
            data: {
              entityName: row['entityName'],
              status: row['status'],
              entityCode: row['entityCode'],
              createdDateString: row['createdDateString'],
            },
          }
          node.children.push(children)
        });
        this.entityListTree = [...this.entityListTree];
      }, 500);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz please?

Comment: did u get the fix?